# Error while trying to install Google Analytics from within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, ide

When I try to enable Google Analytics to my existing project from Android Studio module config (F4) I get this error :

`IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'userEmail' of com/google/gct/login/CredentialedUserRoster.setActiveUser must not be null`

I tried disabling Google Login and reenabling it, no success.

I tried revoking Android Studio access in Google Panel, no success.